# API that can give the latitude and longitude ranges from the address

Tags: geocoding, api, geolocation, bbox

Is there any API available that can get the latitude and longitude boundaries from the address.

For example if we provide: 12380 Sunnyvale avenue, CA, 90005

Can we get the latitude minimum and maximum, longitude minimum and maximum for that address?

Comment: If that's a single postal address then do you want the boundary of the building or the parcel of land? I very much doubt either exist except in specialised local land management systems. Have you looked at the Google Maps API? Do you want USA only? Or only some states?

Comment: Usually geocoding API's return a single LAT/LON for the location of the address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nominatim gives the bounding box (max/min latitude and longitude) using  the api. see this

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=12380%20Sunnyvale%20avenue,%20CA,%2090005&format=json

`"boundingbox":["35.155971","35.156072","-117.79738","-117.792992"],`

Comment: Thanks for the answer this works for me

Comment: Please mark it as accepted.

Comment: What does that bounding box describe? The land parcel?